# How can I get an algorithm to do a exponentiation of a float exponent?

Tags: exponentiation

I'm developing a small application in Deluge (zoho.com). There isn't a "^" operator or a "pow" function to do exponentiation. Getting worst, I'm supposed to do exponentiations also with float exponents, instead just integer exponents. I've found a lot of algorithms doing integer exponentiations, but none that do it for float ones. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are basically same. If you want something simple, then repeatedly multiplying would do.
If you want to make the multiplication process efficient, you can go for [Divide and conquer algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithm),

Comment: I must to implement a function that would do an exponentiation either of a integer base and exponent and a float base and exponent. The integer algorithm couldn't do it:

Comment: float math.potencia(float base, int expoente)
{
    //retorno = 1.1;
    
    if(expoente>0)
    {
    base = base * thisapp.math.potencia(base, (input.expoente  -  1));
    }
    else if (expoente == 0)
    {
    base = 1;
    }
    return base;
}